# Navigate to Apache Calcite code in Intellij Idea while debugging

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-calcite, janino, shardingsphere

How can I navigate to Calcite's code while debugging another Intellij Idea project which uses Calciteas a maven dependency ? I was troubleshooting Apache shardingsphere and I found that the issue happends inside Calcite dependdency. But while navigating to Calcite, Intellij cannot decompile the source files. It just shows 'Unknown Source' in the call stack aswell.

While researching I found that Calcite uses Janino to generate Jar files and I need special java VM flags to generate and navigate to Calcite's classes. Still I coudn't make it work.